# How can I hide or show answers in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm displaying a list of questions along with their answers and correct answer. For this purpose I'm using `<table>` for each question I'm displaying. So there will be the same no. of `<table>`s present on the page as no. of questions displayed.

Now there is one hyperlink present in each question titled "Hide-Show Answers" (for now only). When user clicks on this hyperlink the 'Options' heading, options for that questions and a correct answer should get hidden if it's showing. If these things are hidden, then upon clicking on the  hyperlink these things should get shown. Initially when page loads everything should be displayed as like now.

Also one more thing is when page loads initially everything would be shown to the user and the text of hyperlink should be "Hide Answers" and when user clicks on this link the content should get hidden and title should change to "Show Answers".

I need to implement this using jQuery as well as Javacript. Can anyone help me in this regard, please? I've following HTML code:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
  <tr class="question_info">
    <td valign="top">
      <b>Question 1.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="15957">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
                              <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                        <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html><body><p>The dimensions of universal gravitational constant are</p></body></html>
                                                                                  <br/><b>QUE15957</b><br/>
                              <a href="#">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <b>Options : </b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

    M-2L2T-2

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

    M-1L3T-2

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

    ML-1T-2

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

    ML2T-2

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <b>Correct Answer :</b> 2   
    </td>
  </tr>              
</table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top">
                          <b>Question 2.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="37672">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">


                          <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>If angular momentum quantum number can take value of <i>n</i> also (in addition to other possible values) then total number of electrons in first orbit would have been :</p></body></html>
                                                                              <br/><b>QUE37672</b><br/>
                          <a href="#">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

6

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

8

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

10

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 3   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top">
                          <b>Question 3.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="38552">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">


                          <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>For figure 24, the correct relation is -<br><img height="110" src="http://www.entranceprime.com/upload_media/questions/original/1328941281_38.JPG" width="172"></p></body></html>
                                                                              <br/><b>QUE38552</b><br/>
                          <a href="#">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=9329a28849bd94b3bcc49e3a4b69a595.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=c8c15583e8f5742625e6d80c71f3a691.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=af6f96bda5c2f575fc42e4751c5772fe.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

All of the above

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 4   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
```

Comment: What is your issue? Where does the code fail? Do you get any errors? Please post your [**current code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) that you are having issues with so we can have a look and try to help you fix it. If possible creating a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar) demonstrating the issue always helps and provides a playground for testing different solutions?

Comment: Also i dont think this html is proper. There are multiple Doctype, html and body tags all over the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the code like this way..

```
$("a").click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault();
$(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:last").toggle();
});
```

and also I would suggest you to give class name for the anchor tags and change the selector accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/21/)

**EDIT**

```
$("a").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if($(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:not(:first)").is(":visible"))
{
    $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
$(this).html("show answer");
}
else
{
    $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:not(:first)").show();
$(this).html("hide answer");
}
});
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/23/)

It would be better if you avoid multiple `<html>` in a single page. You can remove it. There  require only one html tag in a page..

Comment: :Actually there are  three <tr> present which I want to hide/show. Options heading, Options itself and the correct answer. Now your code is hiding only correct answer. How should hide other things too?

Comment: you want to hide all the options?

Comment: Yes, the Options heading, all the four options and a correct answer. All the three <tr>

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working as per my expectation. But the motion of hiding and showing the content is too fast. Can you make it smooth?

Comment: yes.. You can animate it.. Use slideToggle() for that

Comment: Can you please make use of that and update your fiddle accordingly?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. But there are some flickering problems. I dont know why.. Its better to try by your own at your local environment. Please accept my answer if it helped you. This is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/24/

Comment: Thanks brother. Your answer is accepted and upvoted too. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the hyperlink of "show answers" an id or class, I would use a class:

```
<a href="#" class="show-ans">show answers</a>
```

And then give the answers a class as well:

```
<p class="ans">Answer 1</p>
```

Now the jQuery:

```
 $(".ans").hide();
 $(".show-ans").click(function(){
     $(".ans").show();
 });
```

This will show the answers when the link is clicked.
If you want it to toggle whether they are shown or hidden replace .show(); with .toggle();

UPDATE:

Give each table row its own separate class, and each answer their own class:

```
 <a href="#" class="q1">show a1</a>
 <a href="#" class="q2">show a2</a>

 <tr class="a1">answer one</tr>
 <tr class="a2">answer two</tr>
```

And then just rewrite the jQuery for each one:

```
 $(".a1").hide();
 $(".a2").hide()
 $(".q1").click(function(){
     $(".a1").toggle();
 });
 $(".q2").click(function(){
     $(".a2").toggle();
 });
```

Comment: :Actually there are three <tr> present which I want to hide/show. There is no single <p> tag as you have done in above example. Then how should I do this on all the three <tr> present for every question?

Comment: @PHPLover: ...or...you could have a go at it and expand the given code. Then if you have issues post a question with the code that troubles you and ask for help **or** use other sites that you can pay a developer for to provide you with a full solution where all you have to do is provide the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$("a").click(function(e){

  $(".options").toggle();
  $(".manage_box tr:nth-child(2)").toggle();
  $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:last").toggle();

});
```